# Mysql User can't connect via localhost but from outside

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

i am trying to connect with my database on a Server via a localhost java app on the server. Everything works fine if i use a remote connection but as soon as my program runs on the server with the Database i can't connect.

I am using an Ubuntu 18.04 Server and i opened and checked the standard 3306 Port in my ufw setup.

I set up my Mysql User for the connections with the following commands

```
CREATE USER 'MYUSER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'MYPASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'MYUSER'@'%';
```

I checked them via SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user; and get this result:

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| MYUSER           | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also in my cnf file i commented out

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
# bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

I am not sure how to check what the actual error is but i guess there are some wrong permissions in my setup. Has someone an idea what i am doing wrong or how i can figure out more details?

Comment: do you have localhost in your hosts file? try `ping localhost` what does it return? you don't need additional user for localhost, delete that entry! you sure you gave the full output from `select user`? another possibility is that you got some empty user for localhost as well, you need to remove it. `drop user ''@'localhost';`

Comment: I get an output like this:

PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms


Thanks for the tip with the localhost user. I will delete it again.

Comment: please check my updated comment for what could possibly go wrong

Comment: @FlashThunder i updated the select User output in my original Post after i removed the unnecessary User. I also tried to drop the empty local user but there wasn't one

Comment: It has to be something else then, maybe a connection problem... you need to debug it in JAVA and get an exact error